# Import a golang module with LFS objects

Tags: git, go, git-lfs, go-modules

I need to import a module with LFS objects into my go project. I already added the module to `go.mod`, but when the go tools download the dependencies into my `~/go/pkg/...` folder, the LFS objects are not downloaded. Instead of the full object, I get the LFS metadata.  This causes my build to fail.

I already went through the `go get` and `go mod` docs but couldn't find anything on this topic. The only workaround I've found to far is to manually download the files post  `go mod download`, but I'm looking for a more official solution.

Comment: How did You add LDS module to go.mod? By `go get` command? DId You use LFS module in Your code? When I add dependencies to my code i make only `go get` and than I can use this module in code.

Comment: No, in my repo I'm not using LFS. The dependency I want to import into my go project is the one that's using LFS. It's something similar to https://github.com/coconaut/gobig, but imagine that https://github.com/coconaut/gobig/blob/master/models/big_binary_1.bin is an actual go class, so it's needed during build.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `go get` uses the standard Git commands to download and fetch repositories, it should be sufficient to have installed Git LFS and run `git lfs install`.  That will install the Git filter configuration that Git LFS needs in your per-user Git configuration and then cloning or pulling the changes should result in the proper LFS files being checked out.

You may also want to use the `--skip-repo` option if you run the command outside of a repository.

Comment: Where does `git lfs install` needs to be installed? In the repo or is it a computer-wide setting?

Comment: `git lfs install --skip-repo` will install its configuration into your `~/.gitconfig`, so it can run from anywhere.  It's per-user; if you want a system-wide setting, add `--system` and run it with appropriate privileges.